# Exception processing errorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot project used to work well on Mac. Today I pull the codes to my Windows lap, then the problem occurred, that the Tomcat error page were displayed instead of my custom error page when there is an error (like 404, 500). Meanwhile, the back-end reported an error:

```
2019-03-22 23:55:18.659 ERROR 11000 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           :Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]**

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;
```

The Spring Boot version is 2.1.13, and the using dependencies are:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

group = 'cn.itscloudy'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

It's a simple demo that dependencies only contains web and thymeleaf.

The `error.html` is under the path `resources/template`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is all the console startup logs

```
2019-03-23 13:15:49.510  INFO 6192 --- [           main] c.i.e.ErrorPageTestApplication           : Starting ErrorPageTestApplication on SkyLand with PID 6192 (F:\WorkSpace_intellij\error_page_test\out\production\classes started by chai in F:\WorkSpace_intellij\error_page_test)
2019-03-23 13:15:49.510  INFO 6192 --- [           main] c.i.e.ErrorPageTestApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-03-23 13:15:50.540  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-03-23 13:15:50.560  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-03-23 13:15:50.560  INFO 6192 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2019-03-23 13:15:50.560  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;D:\mysql-5.7.21\bin;F:\tomcat\bin;F:\gradle-4.4.1\bin;D:\Git\cmd;D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\bin;F:\Node.js\;F:\Python\Scripts\;F:\Python\;D:\MATLAB\runtime\win64;D:\MATLAB\bin;D:\MATLAB\polyspace\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;F:\Redis;F:\Python\Scripts\django-admin.exe;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;F:\Python\Scripts\;F:\Python\;C:\Users\chai\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\chai\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
2019-03-23 13:15:50.670  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-03-23 13:15:50.670  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1080 ms
2019-03-23 13:15:50.859  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-03-23 13:15:50.949  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2019-03-23 13:15:51.029  INFO 6192 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-03-23 13:15:51.029  INFO 6192 --- [           main] c.i.e.ErrorPageTestApplication           : Started ErrorPageTestApplication in 2.138 seconds (JVM running for 4.394)
```

It will jump to the classical Tomcat 404 page, not the `error.html` if I visit an non-exist page. The back-end will report the error which I demonstrated in the top.

I Googled it a lot, but still don't why. Then I tried 1.5.9 version of Spring Boot, it worked! But I don't want to change the version of Spring Boot because I had to change plenty of codes

What is the reason this problem was caused and how to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

There's an additional error in the log,this doesn't make much sense.
This exception does not affect the program,  You can use the below code for turning off log at this exception level in applicaton.yml,if you really don’t want to see it.

```
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase: off
```

Answer (score -3):

The problem was handled after I updated IDEA to the newest version.